# Google Sheets. Is it possible to give a word a value?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I want to give words number values.

Eg. Monthly =12, Quartly = 4

What are some ways I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not think there is a way to do that but don't take my word for it. Have you took a look at the help forum?

Comment: Is this link useful https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127831/is-it-possible-to-have-named-constants-in-google-sheets  ?  
Specifically you can create VB  function monthly() {return 12;}, etc

Comment: There are many ways to do this (quite easily), but it would depend on your context. Right now, we just have an idea floating in cyberspace. If you'd like to set up a sample spreadsheet illustrating your actual use case, I think you'll get more targeted answers. Just share the link back here, being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link ... Editor."

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Named Range feature to name a cell. They can be in another sheet even (not another document, another sheet in the same document)

Steps

1. In the menus Click Data and then Named ranges. A menu will open on the right.
2. In a cell type `12`
3. Select the cell with 12 in it
4. Click "Add Range" on the right
5. Type `Monthly` for the name
6. Click Done

Repeat the steps 2 to 6 for `Quarterly`

Now in some other cell (even on another sheet in the same document) type `=Monthly` in a cell or `=Quarterly` or Use those names in formulas

See [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Here's a screenshot. I created a sheet called constants and typed 12 and 4 in 2 cells. I've named the first cell `Monthly` and the 2nd cell `Quarterly`

[image]

Then in Sheet1 I can reference those names in forumla

[image]

Answer (score 1):

or you can do it directly like:

```
=IF(A1 = "Monthly"; 12; 
 IF(A1 = "Quartly"; 4; ))
```